# Genetic algorithm - evolve only one object

Tags: artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm, 2d-games, pong

I have an AI class and we have to make projects. I chose to do a genetic algorithm and since I'm new to the concept I have couple of questions. I have researched and I get the idea and followed Coding Train's video on simple genetic algorithm without any problem. However i have seen multiple videos on YouTube where cars evolve, and I don't get how do they have population of lets say 20 if only one car is being rendered to the screen. I wanna try and create Pong like game(I'll use basic physics engine) where  Player A is computer, which always follows the Y coordinate of the ball thus can't lose, and Player B is supposed to evolve using genetic algorithm. How would I evolve Player B every time it loses. What would the chromosomes be? What would the population be? If you can give me any advice I would be very thankful

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the cars, it's most likely that each car in the generation is being evaluated and rendered sequentially. Suppose the population size is 20, the first 20 cars you see would be the initial population. The next 20 cars you see would be the second generations population and so on.

Regarding Pong, you need to decide on a fitness function for your Player B. If Player B always loses then perhaps your fitness function could be how long it is able to last before it loses.  To determine your chromosome you first need to decide how you will control Player B's paddle. The chromosome would then be some set of design variables that affect that system. For example, you might use a small neural net where your chromosome encodes the weights of the connections. Your population is a set of chromosomes used to produce the next generations set of chromosomes through crossover and mutation.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I made program which learns to shoot basketball into a hoop to practice genetic algorithms and it works perfectly. I havn't done any neural networks so far so ill look into that. Would you say neural networks are harder than gentetic?

Comment: I'm glad to hear the GA worked. The applications of GAs and neural networks can be quite different, I only mentioned a neural network in regards to the Pong program. They aren't mutually exclusive either. There are many approaches to designing or training a neural network. You could certainly use a GA in some cases, although this may not be the best approach. I recommended continuing to read up on both topics and pay attention to the types of problems that are being solved by each.

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time to help